# Update the print text

Tags: python, printing, stopwatch

I want the print to update the days, hours, minutes and seconds, and not to write a new sentence with the updated data. So now it shows per example: 
1 tage, 2 stunden, 3 minuten, 40 sekunden
1 tage, 2 stunden, 3 minuten, 39 sekunden
and so on...

All i want is to update the numbers, without writing a new line.

I hope you can help me,

Here's the code:

```
#%%Import stuff
import time
import webbrowser
import os

#%% Type in your Values
days = 0
hours = 4
mins = 0
secs = 0

#%% Functions
counter = ((days * 86400) + (hours * 3600) + (mins * 60) + secs)

def StartCounter(counter):
    if counter < 0:
        print("Error, type in a positiv counter, Idiot")
    Music(counter)
    while counter > 0:
        Darstellung(counter)
        time.sleep(1)
        counter += -1
    message = "Fertig"

    return message 

def Check():
    if StartCounter(counter) == "Fertig":
        print("Counter finished!")
        os.system("H:\Bearbeitet\Stopuhr\Song\Wecker.mp3")
    else:
        StartCounter(counter)   

def Music(counter):
    if counter >= 90:
        if counter >= 200:
            if counter >= 3600:
                if counter >= 86400:
                    webbrowser.open("spotify:user:vostry.janek:playlist:3Rxuq9vevFUYJh4fJ7T9kC")
                else:
                    webbrowser.open("H:\Bearbeitet\Stopuhr\Song\LangWarten.m4a")
            else:
                webbrowser.open("H:\Bearbeitet\Stopuhr\Song\Warten.mp3")
        else:
            webbrowser.open("H:\Bearbeitet\Stopuhr\Song\Song.mp3")
    else: 
        webbrowser.open("H:\Bearbeitet\Stopuhr\Song\Sarah.mp3")

def Darstellung(counter):
    tage = 0
    stunden = 0
    minuten = 0
    sekunden = 0
    while counter > 0:
        if counter >= 86400:
            counter += -86400
            tage += +1
        else:
            if counter >= 3600:
                counter += -3600
                stunden += +1
            else:
                if counter >= 60:
                    counter += -60
                    minuten += +1
                else:
                    counter += -1
                    sekunden += +1
    print("%s Tage, %s Stunden, %s Minuten und %s Sekunden" % (tage, stunden, minuten, sekunden), "\n")

#%% Run
Check()
```

Comment: You seem to be programming in a different paradigm to Python. What language are you coming from?

Comment: I am coming from Austria and programmed with C# before

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by using a return carriage character. The return carriage character is \r or you have to tell print to not use \n as the ending character so your print statement would become

Python 3:

`print(tage, " Tage, ", stunden, " Stunden, ", minuten, " Minuten und ", sekunden, " Sekunden", end="\r")`

Hope that helps!

Comment: i tried but the output was: 0 Stunden, 0 Minuten und 11 Sekunden0 Tage, 0 Stunden, 0 Minuten und 10 Sekunden0 Tage, 0 Stunden, 0 Minuten und 9 Sekunden0 Tage, 0 Stunden, 0 Minuten und 8 Sekunden0 Tage, 0 Stunden, 0 Minuten und 7 Sekunden0 Tage, 0 Stunden, 0 Minuten und 6 Sekunden0 Tage, 0 Stunden, 0 Minuten und 5 Sekunden0 Tage, 0 Stunden, 0 Minuten und 4 Sekunden0 Tage, 0 Stunden, 0 Minuten und 3 Sekunden0 Tage, 0 Stunden, 0 Minuten und 2 Sekunden0 Tage, 0 Stunden, 0 Minuten und 1 SekundenCounter finished!

Comment: Are you running python 2 or python 3?

Comment: It's running in Python 3.6

Comment: That is very odd because I can run this on python 3, and 3.6 with the desired output.

Comment: Please run print(sys.version_info) and give us the output. You have to import sys first.

Comment: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: ---Windows 7---

Comment: That doesn't work because the print in is a Method which gets called every second.

Comment: Sorry I don't know I have only ever used linux. I believe it has something to do with how windows decided to re-invent the wheel and create their own line ending.